# Gravitational waves: simulations of signal

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, gravitational-waves, software, signal-processing

I am self-learning GR.

I was wondering if there is any open source software to help learn more about the signal processing of gravitational waves. E.g. a software that injects a signal into random noise and outputs data accordingly.

I am interested in trying to do some signal processing now that I have learned the basics of gravitational waves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LIGO actually has a really nice step-by-step tutorial on this: https://losc.ligo.org/s/events/GW150914/GW150914_tutorial.html

It is in python, but should be accessible

[image]

There is more in LIGO Open Science Center: https://losc.ligo.org/tutorials/

Comment: Thanks. True, I've actually went through the said tutorial but forgot to add it in my answer. Anyhow, I think this is more useful than the two links posted in my answer.

Comment: There are also [interactive tutorials](https://notebooks.azure.com/nitz/libraries/pycbc) that one can run in the browser to get some idea of parts of what LIGO data analysis is doing.

Answer (score 2):

Alright so the LIGO collaboration has established a multitude of software for doing this.

**lalsuite**

One of the more commonly used ones is [lalsuite](https://www.lsc-group.phys.uwm.edu/daswg/projects/lalsuite.html). Some examples:

> lalsim-detector-noise --aligo-zerodet-highpower -s 1000000000 -t 16 > noise
>
> lalsim-inspiral | lalsim-detector-strain -D H1 -a 1:23:45 -d 45.0 -p 30.0 -t 1000000008 > signal
>
> lalsim-inject noise signal > output

creates noise and inputs a signal into it.

**pycbc**

Another, more user-friendly version is [pycbc for combact binary coalescence](https://github.com/ligo-cbc/pycbc), which is a python interface for doing gravitational wave physics (including data analysis and mock data challenges).